# Intercept a request and internally forward to controller?

Tags: java, spring

I've got a project which is divided in different modules, you have for example a site and a forum.

The forum can be found at:

```
http://example.com/[forum]/
```

and for example can be:

```
http://example.com/support/
http://example.com/helpme/
http://example.com/aforum/
```

The site can be found at:

```
http://example.com/[site]/
```

and for example can be:

```
http://example.com/site1/
http://example.com/nice/
http://example.com/something/
```

The [forum] and [site] part are variable. In my database i lookup that "nice" is a site, "helpme" is a forum.

I have a spring RequestMapping for my ForumController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{simpleTitle:[0-9a-z-]+}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public void list(@PathVariable String simpleTitle, Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
```

I have the samething for sites, so a SiteController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{simpleTitle:[0-9a-z-]+}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public void list(@PathVariable String simpleTitle, Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
```

This of course goes bad, cause 2 controllers with the same requestmapping isn't good.

I can create a FrontController which with above request mapping, lookup what simpleTitle is (a forum or a site) and call functions to display a forum or a site. That works.

But it isn't very "spring" like and structured.

Is it possible "intercept" a request and internally forward (or call the function) on the controller myself?

This way i could have Interceptor which looks a simpleTitle, decides whether it is a forum or site, and "forwards"/"calls" the right controller.

Comment: Not sure if this is spring-ish for you, but you can obtain a spring bean with a parameter S (for site) or F (for forum) and this bean will do the redirect internally. You will implement a common interface for the implementations of (S)ite and (F)orum. You can abstract the retrieval of the path in another bean.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That sure sounds spring-ish ;-) Although i'm having trouble understanding it, can you explain it a bit further please? No big example needed, just the basics or maybe just an url that explains it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers Luiggi Mendoza and witchedwiz for the great ideas!

While i was eating i came up with a very simple solution: use servlet filter. Add a request header with a HttpServletRequestWrapper (type: forum or type: site) inside the doFilter.

In the @RequestMapping add a headers property like headers = "type=forum".

Now @RequestMapping can have the same urls, they differ in request header. And all spring functionality works, although i only made a simple test case so far.

WebApplicationContextUtils helped to get spring beans in the servlet filter.

Comment: I've avoided this alternative because it will wrap all the paths and it's not spring-ish :P. Anway, glad to know you found something that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly I like @Luiggi Mendoza solution, but if you want an alternative, use something like this:

```
            package eu.europa.acer.aris.ceremp.filter;

        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
        import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
        import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;


        @Component(value = "yourCustomFilter")
        public class YourCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

            private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourCustomFilter.class);

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                //String[] path = request.getRequestURL().toString().split("/");

                            if (letPagePass(request.getRequestURL().toString()) == false)
                            {   
                                // if request is bound to static resource like js//img do nothing, the filter chain will activate
                                if (letResourcePass(request.getRequestURL().toString()))
                                {

                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    String[] urlInfos = obtainUrlAndParametersLast(request.getRequestURL().toString());
                                    // last element will always give back  last part including any parameter
                                    // first element will always be a controller modifier
                                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+rebuildControllerPath(urlInfos));
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

            }

            private String rebuildControllerPath(String[] pathElement )
            {
                //do your thing here
                if ("forum".equals(pathElement[0]))
                {
                String addenda = "/forumController/";
                for (String singlePart: pathElement)
                {
                    addenda = addenda+singlePart+"/";
                }
                return addenda;
                }

            }

            // bind forceful redirect
            public boolean letPagePass(String url)
            {
                // if you have some page that are naturally unique among controllers that you want always to process natively
                String[] path = url.split("/");
                if (path[path.length-2].startsWith("yourCertainUrlIgnoringParameters"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                // directcall
                else if (path[path.length-2].startsWith("yourCertainUrlIgnoringParameters2"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public boolean letResourcePass(String url)
            {
                String[] path = url.split("/");

                /*
                this assumes you have always a strict structure so your image//js//reource will always be in
                https://domainname/a/lot/of/folder/img/actuaresource.png
                or
                https://domainname/a/lot/of/folder/js/actuaresource.js
                etc
                */
                //image pass
                if (path[path.length-2].equals("img") || url.contains("/img/"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                //css pass
                else if (path[path.length-2].equals("css")  || url.contains("/css/"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                //js pass
                else if (path[path.length-2].equals("js")  || url.contains("/js/"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void destroy() {
            }

        }
```

and add to your web.xml file the following xml snippet

```
        <!--  your fi Filter -->
            <filter>
                <filter-name>yourCustomFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
            </filter>
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>yourCustomFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
```